# Nutch Crawl does not working

Tags: solr, nutch

I want to crawl a site using Apache Nutch 1.12 and index the data into Apache Solr. I have followed this [tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial).

My seed.txt file has this url http://nutch.apache.org/

In my regex url filter I am having like this  +^http://([a-z0-9]*.)*nutch.apache.org/

when I try to fetch the data i am getting only the url in my seed.txt file.

```
Fetcher: starting at 2017-01-03 09:56:23
Fetcher: segment: crawl/segments/20170103095613
Fetcher: threads: 10
Fetcher: time-out divisor: 2
QueueFeeder finished: total 2 records + hit by time limit :0
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
fetching http://nutch.apache.org/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Using queue mode : byHost
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
robots.txt whitelist not configured.
robots.txt whitelist not configured.
-activeThreads=2, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=2
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=0
-activeThreads=0
```

What i am missing here.

Comment: try recursively, Generate > Fetch > Parse > Updatedb . see your logs entries for more details

Answer (score 0):

I tried to perform fetch operation one more time I am getting the expected results.